# Simple tunnel build fails - NEAppProxyErrorDomain

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I downloaded the last version of SimpleTunnel.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/SimpleTunnel/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016140-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2

I have Xcode 8.1.

When I try to build that project I receive 2 times the error `"Use of undeclared type 'NEAppProxyErrorDomain'"` in **ClientAppProxyConnection** file, in these lines:

```
func handleErrorCondition(_ flowError: NEAppProxyErrorDomain? = nil, notifyServer: Bool = true) {

func closeConnection(_ direction: TunnelConnectionCloseDirection, flowError: NEAppProxyErrorDomain?) {
```

I tried to clean the project and rebuild them several times, and I deleted the entire project and downloaded again, etc...

What can I do?

Regards,

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Replace "NEAppProxyErrorDomain" with "NEAppProxyFlowError.Code" will work.

Comment: Excellent - can you share how you figured this out? Just searching in the docs?

Comment: I'm curious as well.

Comment: This thread has a lot of useful information about fixing the outdated SimpleTunnel code, including the explanation for the above answer: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/67583

Comment: Pardon my language but please, Apple employees, KEEP YOUR BLOODY SAMPLE CODE UP TO DATE! Am so fed up with fixing broken Swift samples.

Answer (score 0):

This only occurs with Xcode 8.1. I installed again Xcode 8.0 and works well.

Comment: Please file a bug report to Apple about the 8.1 behavior.

Comment: I filed that bug. Bug number 29217001